# Do I make viewmodels for each page?

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm

I'm creating a game where I have a lot of different pages. For instance: loginpage, profilepage, playersfriendeditpage.

Do I create a ViewModel for each of them? They are all dealing with the model, "player", but in diffeent aspect. Whats common sense?

Comment: Your ViewModel should contain only those properties that are going to be used by the View, so in theory if all those pages use different properties, then yes, you should create different ViewModels

Comment: @Jason94 You can have a base viewmodel for common properties and create individual viewmodels based on each page

Comment: @Deepu... I'd fill this out and upgrade this to an answer...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It depends on the way you design your database.
If you want all the fields to be in a same table you can keep them under the same view model and this is not the case with most of the cases because you wouldn't like to have any redundant information in your database and you want your database to be normalized. So you can structure your models depending on your database design so that your database has no redundant information.

Comment: ViewModels shouldn't have anything to do with the database design.

Answer (score 1):

Well since a view model acts as interface to your model from your view, it makes sense that any time a view needs to modify a model differently than any other view has, you'll want a new view model.

In other words, even though various views may LOOK different, it's the interaction with the model/view model that dictates whether a new view model is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If your page contains a ton of stuff, it may make sense to break them up into sub VMs. I try to think of a ViewModel as just a class and like any other class, you don't want it to do EVERYTHING if it doesn't make sense to. If your page is logically broken up into a mini-views, then you should be able to easy encompass those needs in a sub-VM.

For example: say you have an edit page that contains all your info. Maybe the user information  (name, address, phone #) is a VM, the work history is a VM and the hobbies section is a VM and your main VM basically does all of the stuff around it. You can use messaging and/or events to handle the communication needs.

Answer (score 0):

ViewModels are useful when you want to create a model that contains an instance of another model.  This is the case when you have a 1 to many relationship between one model and another (one table and another) and need to display both information on the same view, for example.  Or not even 1 to many necessarily, but that's often the case.

If you have a drop down list that contains values populated from a table in a database, but your View should display all other information from a different model, for example, you would use a ViewModel in this example.

Answer (score 0):

I would define a ViewModel as *an **abstraction** of a view.* The viewModel should contain properties and methods which provide the **Data** and **behaviour** that a view requires to function correctly.

Given this definition my instinct would be to provide a separate viewModel for each view as they are each likely to have their own unique behaviour.

The fact that all views depend on the same `Player` entity is an implementation detail and as has already been suggested this functionality should be moved into a base class that the other viewModels can derive from, something along the lines of this:

```
public abstract class ScreenViewModel : ViewModelBase // Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Player _currentPlayer;

    public ScreenViewModel(IRepository<Player> playerRepository)
    {
        // Retrieve desired player from the repository.
        this._currentPlayer = playerRepository.Find(...);
    }

    // This is an idea of the sort of thing you can do; derived viewModels
    // do not need to worry about loading the player, they can just consume
    // it and provide the screen specific behaviour.
    protected Player CurrentPlayer
    {
        get { return _currentPlayer; }
    }
}
```

I don't agree with the advice provided in the currently accepted answer as it is wrong; it is your **views** that should shape your viewModels not your database. The design of the database **should have little or no bearing on the design of your viewModels**. The whole point of having a viewModel between your view and your domain layer is to insulate your application from changes in the lower layers.

In fact, if you look at the example viewModel I have provided it is fairly well insulated from those sorts of changes. The Player would typically be exposed as a POCO (making it persistence ignorant) and the repository that provides access to those entities is hidden behind an interface.

This means I could change the way the database structure is implemented and these changes would be absorbed by the data layer (e.g. by changing the way Entity Framework maps the tables to the entities in the application) and the viewModel would require no changes. You could even change the persistence mechanism (I.E. save data to a custom file rather than a database) and as long as it mapped the data to the `Player` POCO and the new repository implemented the `IRepository<Player>` interface your viewModel would still work as expected, demonstrating that the database structure has little or no bearing on the design of your viewModels.